# Page file in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, pagefile

I have recently got a new laptop with Windows 10 installed, and noticed that instead of 235GB my TotalCommander lists only 133GB as busy and 91GB as free, so 224GB in total and I have little idea where the rest is: I switched on viewing all the hidden and system files.

My original idea was that this space is taken by the pagefile, since that aligns with my 16GB of RAM, however for some reason this file is not present in the root of c: drive (the only one I have). When I looked in the system setting, I got even more surprised: my pagefile is automatically set to be only 3GB. So my question is: where can I find it, and shouldn't I make it bigger? Previously I followed the rule of thumb that its size should be at least the size of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the size hasn't changed in Windows 10, it is [still in system properties](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=52).

[image]

All the "rules" that you can find are crap. Let Windows manage the size and by happy.

To see the size of all folder, run [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/?language=EN) as admin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I knew where to find it, that's how I saw that it was only 3GB. Ok, I'll won't change the size manually and let it be adjusted by OS itself. I'll also use TreeSize to try to find it, however I still don't understand why is this file is not in root of my c:. According to Microsoft, that's where it should be.\

Comment: on which drive have you found the page file?

Comment: I've installed the TreeSize, and it found it out. I have only one drive, c: and Windows has also indicated that the file is located there. Strangely I don't see it in TotalCommander or Windows explorer, even with hidden items. Now everything adds up, thanks!